# How to query intermediate table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two classes in ruby:-

```
   class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
       # attr_accessible :title, :body
       acts_as_authorization_role :subject_class_name => 'User', :join_table_name =>   "roles_users"
    end
```

and

```
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_authentic
          acts_as_authorization_object :role_class_name => 'Role', :subject_class_name => 'User'
          acts_as_authorization_subject :association_name => :roles , :join_table_name => 'roles_users'
          has_one:employee_detail ,:foreign_key => "User_id"

     end
```

and migration files are:-

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :username
     t.string :email
     t.string :crypted_password
     t.string :password_salt
     t.string :persistence_token
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end


 class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table "roles" , :force => true  do |t|
      t.string  :name ,             :limit => 40
      t.string  :authorizable_type, :limit => 40
      t.integer :authorizable_id
      t.timestamps
   end
 end
end


 class RolesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table "roles_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.references  :user
    t.references  :role
  end
 end
end
```

i have user id and want to retrieve role id, but not able to query intermediate table. can anyone provide some solution for this. thnks

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your user is going to have multiple roles

You can define an habtm relation in user for for role and get retrive roles roles like following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_authentic
      acts_as_authorization_object :role_class_name => 'Role', :subject_class_name => 'User'
      acts_as_authorization_subject :association_name => :roles , :join_table_name => 'roles_users'
      has_one:employee_detail ,:foreign_key => "User_id"
      has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

And retrieve roles for a user like below

```
user = User.find user_id
user.roles # this will give you roles array
role_ids = user.roles.map { |r| r.id } # if you only want array of ids
```